# Numerical Computation Matlab

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab, newton-raphson

I am trying to solve the fifty problems $f_i(\theta) = 0, \ i = 1, ..., 50,$ where

$$f_i (\theta) = \theta - \sin(\theta) - \frac{i}{100}$$

I was told I must solve these in ascending order of $i$ and with a maximum of 200 evaluations of $f$ or its derivatives.

I tried to solve this in Matlab using Newton's method, with the following iteration formula:

$$\theta_{n+1} = \theta_n - \frac{f(\theta_n)}{f'(\theta_n)} = \theta_n - \frac{\theta_n- \sin(\theta_n) - \frac{i}{100}}{1- cos(\theta_n)}$$

Here's my basic Matlab code for one iteration applied to each problem:

```
x=0.01;
for i=1:1:50
    x=x - ((x-sin(x)-(i/100))/(1-(cos(x))))
end
```

However I think the question asks for 200 iterations per problem, so I modified the code to:

```
for i=1:1:50
    n_itn=200;
    x(1)=0.01;
    for k = 1:n_itn
    x(k+1)=x(k) - ((x(k)-sin(x(k))-(i/100))/(1-(cos(x(k)))))
    end
end
```

But I get an extremely long answer, here's a part of it:

```
  Columns 196 through 198

  -0.000004145710670  -0.000002034384641  -0.000000336803024

  Columns 199 through 201

  -0.000000117100873   0.000000102162712  -0.000150151084928
```

So, I am not sure which part of this is my solution. So, what is wrong with my code? Am I even on the right track?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "with a maximum of 200 evaluations": if no requirement is given in terms of accuracy, this constraint is a nonsense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I'm not so sure. It seems like it is "come up with the best approximation you can under this requirement". The requirement ultimately forces them into a predictor-corrector method, since random initial guesses will require more than 4 function evaluations for a given step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the aim of this task is to teach you the wonders of the homotopy continuation method. Thus the goal is to solve
$$
x-\sin x =\frac12
$$
which then gets subdivided into 50 steps raising the "watermark" of the right side from $0$ to $\frac12$, where the initial problem
$$
x-\sin x=0
$$
has the easy (and unique) solution $x_0=0$.

The idea is that if $x_k$ is a good solution to
$$
x-\sin x=\frac{k}{100}
$$
then the error $f_{k+1}(x_k)=-\frac1{100}$ leads after two Newton iterations to an error of magnitude $(0.01)^{2^2}=10^{-8}$.

Two Newton iterations because 200 evaluations of $f$ and $f'$ for 50 problems leads to an average of 4 evaluations equal to 2 Newton steps.

Since the solution for $k=0$ is singular, one can not start the iteration for $x_1$ with $x=x_0=0$. Better approximate $x-\sin x\simeq\frac16x^3$ and thus start the iteration with $x=\sqrt[3]{\frac3{50}}=0.3914867641169…$ for $k=1$ and similar for further small $k$. Then use linear extrapolation to get good initial values. (Basic homotopy uses constant continuation.)

---

```
x = zeros(1,50);
for k=1:1:50
    if k<10 then
        x(k) = (3*k/50)^(1/3);
    else
        x(k) = 2*x(k-1)-x(k-2);
    end  
    for m = 1:2
        x(k) = x(k) - ( x(k)-sin(x(k))-k/100 ) / ( 1-cos(x(k))  );
    end
end
```

leading to results (partial list

```
k           x(k)          x(k) - sin(x(k))
-----------------------------------------
 1.    0.3924933889707    0.0100000000013
 2.    0.4952635544934    0.0200000000157
 3.    0.5676633468267    0.0300000000686
 4.    0.6255141630440    0.0400000001950
 5.    0.6745314424308    0.0500000004379
 6.    0.7175125729004    0.0600000008470
 7.    0.7560609279733    0.0700000014780
 8.    0.7911911702720    0.0800000023919
 9.    0.8235909073405    0.0900000036545
10.    0.8537501566741    0.1000000000114
15.    0.9811216100757    0.1500000000005
20.    1.0836918803146    0.2000000000001
25.    1.1712296525017    0.2500000000000
30.    1.2485154675427    0.3
35.    1.3182890721987    0.35
40.    1.382284133718     0.4
45.    1.4416754785973    0.45
50.    1.4973003890959    0.5
```

Comment: A followup remark: this approach is called "natural" continuation. You have a point on the solution curve in $(p,x)$ space; you extrapolate somehow; you hold $p$ fixed at the extrapolation value and correct to the solution. This has a problem when the solution looks like $p=x^2$; then the curve can "turn around" and natural continuation will never see it.

Comment: A variant is called arclength continuation. This uses the same "problem" equations, but replaces the requirement that $p$ stay fixed with the requirement that we search for the solution along directions perpendicular to the direction of extrapolation (in $(p,x)$ space). This can still sometimes break down, especially in higher dimensions, but it addresses the problem of going around a turning point (which is actually a particular type of bifurcation).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. But the problem explicitly states that we must start from initial estimate $0.01$. Could you also please explain the steps how you obtained $\left( \frac{3}{50} \right)^{1/3}$?

Comment: Then please update your question with the exact statements of your task description on initial points and in which way the function evaluations are counted. -- $1/100=x-\sin x= x-(x-\frac16x^3+\frac1{120}x^5\mp…)\approx \frac16 x^3\iff x^3\approx 6/100=3/50\iff x\approx \sqrt[3]{3/50}$.

Comment: Thank you, using $(0.06)^{1/3}$ this works perfectly now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be iterating over the same x(i) therefore the index of x should be i not k+1. Hence:

x(i)=0.01;

and

x(i)=x(i) - ((x(i)-sin(x(i))-(i/100))/(1-(cos(x(i)))));

```
n_itn=200;
x = 0.01*ones(1,50);
for i=1:1:50    
    for k = 1:n_itn
        x(i)=x(i) - ((x(i)-sin(x(i))-(i/100))/(1-(cos(x(i)))));
    end
end
```

Comment: 200 is the number of evaluations of $f$ or $f'$, thus 100 Newton steps. It is ridiculous to do 100 Newton steps for one problem. In floating point double for such simple scalar problems, one either has a solution in 15 steps or one needs another initial point.